# How to deploy Typescript project on Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run

```
Cloud Run error: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

My project uses port 8080. But Cloud Run doesn't seem to recognize it. It seems that the JavaScript node js did not need to be set separately, but it seems to be necessary here. I use ts-node to open ports normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud Run works with Typescript. However, Buildpacks doesn't know how to manage it.

Why am I talking about Buildpacks? Because your issue should come from your deployment mode. You shoud do `gcloud run deploy source=. ...` and let the Cloud Run service doing the things automatically.

When you do that, the source are set to Cloud Build and Buildpack is used to build the container automatically. It works great with a subset of languages: nodejs, go, java, ruby, python (but you have to add stuff),...

Typescript is not supported yet.

---

The solution here is to add a Dockerfile that help Cloud Build to build a correct container, with the required layer to install the sufficient library to run your code. Having a Dockerfile in the directory bypass Buildpack and use Docker Build command instead.

Comment: Are there any conventions about the Dockerfile for GCloud?

Comment: Thank you Guillaume. Do you have an example Dockerfile for this?

Comment: I'm not a node/typescript developer. But AFAIK, you can run a `npm build` then a `npm serve` or `start`. You simple have to do the same thing. Use a base container with node installed (with the correct version) and then install the deps, build your code and run it in the entrypoint. It should work

Comment: is it possible to precompile the project and then set `source=build` when deploying?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can do all the transformation/compilation that you want before, and then deploy with Cloud Run --source=<dir>. Cloud Run will take the source, package them in a container and run them on itself. No transformation during the process, so, perform the transform before

Answer (score 1):

Include Dockerfile with sample content

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:18

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install application dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of your application code to the container
COPY . .

# Specify the command to run your Node.js application
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Also include .dockerignore and add node_modules